# Check which marker has been clicked - display dialog information

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

As in tittle. I was looking for some solution. In other hand, what I want to achieve is the whole markers display on googlemaps, after click one of them all I need to do is display alertdialog or dialog with some specific information. But I dont know how to define which of them has been clicked.

Here is my GoogleMap class. Hope for some examples. Really need to achieve that..

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
Button logoutButton;
TextView time_text;
TextView distance_text;

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private CalculateDistanceTime distance_task;

private Marker marker1;
private Marker marker2;
boolean isSecond = false;
Polyline lastPolyline;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View decor_View = getWindow().getDecorView();

    int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    decor_View.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);

    UiChangeListener();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
    time_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_text);
    distance_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_text);

    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };


    distance_task = new CalculateDistanceTime(this);
    Polyline lastpolyline;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

private void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.custom_google_map));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }


        marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(51.1117744, 17.0353596))
                .title("Giselle French Bakery Cafe")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));


    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("You are here");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

public void UiChangeListener() {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            }
        }
    });
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;


    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


    String sensor = "sensor=false";


    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    String output = "json";


    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
}

public static String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);

    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Connecting to url
    urlConnection.connect();

    // Reading data from url
    try (InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while down", e.toString());
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {


    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {


        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            if (isSecond) {
                lastPolyline.remove();
                lastPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            } else {
                lastPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                isSecond = true;
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng, marker.getPosition());
    distance_task.setLoadListener(new CalculateDistanceTime.taskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance) {
            distance_text.setText(time_distance[0]); //Distance
            time_text.setText(time_distance[1]); //Time
        }
    });
    String url = getDirectionsUrl(latLng, marker.getPosition());
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(url);

    return false;
}
```

Thanks guys !

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `onMarkerClick` tells you which marker was clicked.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need something like check which exacly one is clicked to display specific information about it. And it would be perfect if it would be longclicklistener

Comment: So is your issue that you don't know how to associate data with each marker?

Comment: Yes. That is it. I dont know how to do this. To display dialog for every single marker with specific information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to associate data with a marker is to use [`marker.setTag(mData)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#associate_data_with_a_marker). You can retrieve this later with `marker.getTag()` and pass it to your alert dialog:

```
marker.setTag("Example data string");

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage(marker.getTag())
        .create()
        .show();
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but how can I display information focus on each marker ? I mean two different popup should have two different information..

Comment: When you say you want a popup, are you referring to a [Dialog](https://i.imgur.com/kSq7Jyk.png) or an [InfoWindow](https://i.imgur.com/4NKLwym.png)?

Comment: At this moment I referring to a Dialog, is that wrong way ?

Comment: Nope! I just wanted to make sure we were thinking of the same thing. I updated my answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all markers and the specific information in a hashmap and get their the string of information for any marker method by calling `markerList.get(marker)`.

```
 private HashMap<Marker, String> markerList = new HashMap<>();
    private GoogleMap mMap; //also instantiate your map 

    private void addMarker(String information, LatLng pos){
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(pos);
        options.title("title");
        Marker mapMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        markerList.put(mapMarker, information);

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve this in my app with that example, could u simplify it

Comment: You are adding a marker on every `onLocationChanged`. So, instead of just adding a marker you can add the marker and store the marker with it's information in a hashmap markerList. And further call `markerList.get(marker)` to get the string of information associated with the marker inside `onMarkerClick`

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me specific example connect with my code ?